# Is "bicep curl" wrong?

Tags: grammatical-number

My Autocorrect is telling me to change it to "bicep**s** curl". Also, the Wikipedia entry is [Biceps curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biceps_curl).

But Googling, the phrase ["bicep curl"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bicep%20curl) seems pretty common. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bicep%20curl%2C%20biceps%20curl&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3) does suggest though that "biceps curl" is thrice as common in books.

Is "bicep curl" wrong and if so, why?

Comment: Don't rely on the auto-correct function for semantic correctness.

Comment: @Lawrence: In this case, though, I would agree with it, because "bicep" is just a back-formation from the originally singular noun "biceps" (from Latin *biceps*)

Comment: Both are syntactically correct and are valid semantically.  It's really a question of which is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

It is "wrong" in the sense that "biceps" is [not a plural word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/biceps-plural-singular) to begin with. The word was directly borrowed from Latin where singular nouns can end in 's'.

> The ceps in biceps, triceps, and quadriceps comes from the Latin word for “head”; the literal meaning of biceps is “two-headed,” referring to a muscle that has two attachments to the bone (this definition of head is “the end of a muscle nearest its origin”).

However, the usage of "bicep" is common enough that in common writing almost all readers would understand what you mean.

> In fact, bicep is used frequently enough that it is entered in the dictionary, where it is defined as a synonym of biceps. Its first recorded use is 1939.

("Usage Notes: Is the Word 'Biceps' Plural or Singular?", Merriam-Webster)